# Pyrogram handler working only in private instead of working everywhere ( using multiple updates with different commands )

Tags: python, pyrogram

The following decorator or filter only works at private but i want this to work everywhere - [private, group]. ( using multiple updates with different commands )

Can anyone correct my mistake done please?

````
         def on():

           self.filter =       (filters.me & filters.command(self.command, self.hndlr) & ~filters.via_bot & ~filters.forwarded)
    

            def handle(function):

                   async def call(client, message): 
                       await function(client, message)
                           
                   system.app.add_handler(MessageHandler(call, filters=self.filter), group=0) 

                   return call
            return handle```
````

Comment: what you mean by working everywhere?

Comment: in private, groups